# Where can I get sources or detailed documentation of /usr/sbin/nas

Tags: openwrt, dd-wrt

I tried to get /usr/bin/nas sources from http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources/nas-4.80.9.1.tar.gz but found that it only contains compiled ELF binaries. I tried to get dd-wrt sources (with hope to find nas there) using the instruction on page http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Development but the crucial instruction `svn co http://svn.dd-wrt.com/DD-WRT` return an error stating the is no source.

I need either detailed parameters of  `/usr/sbin/nas` (as specified by `nas --help` or `man nas` if only dd/open-wrt had man pages) or nas sources.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.bingner.com/openwrt/wpa.html) the nas in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "source" code for `nas` in DD-WRT can be found here: http://svn.dd-wrt.com/browser#src/router/nas

OpenWRT is what you have already seen.

To me it appears that `nas` is a (possibly closed source?) binary that has been repackaged into these two distributions as a binary blob, obtained from somewhere else.

After a bit more digging I found source code for what appears to be the same program on GitHub, which hopefully answers your question:  https://github.com/jcolp/rtn66u/tree/master/release/src/router/nas

TBH, I guessed this by running `strings` on the `nas` binary and discovered the C source files `nas_wksp.c` and `nas_wksp_radius.c` were named probably for debugging.

There is version buried inside the Tomato firmware as well: http://repo.or.cz/w/tomato.git/tree/620424a4333f6eeaf57d8b76ee61a287b6c01683:/release/src-rt/wl/nas

Why the source is not referenced DD-WRT and OpenWRT I have no idea...

Comment: `nas` probably includes proprietary code from Broadcom for their wireless chips. DD-WRT has an agreement with them to bundle support for Broadcom chips in DD-WRT however they can't share the source code.